# Get dpedia data through cross domain ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, cors, dbpedia

I am trying to get the JSON data from the link http://dbpedia.org/data/Mountain_View,_California.json. However I am unable to get it, because `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is missing from the response. I have read online that this used to work before.

Here is the code snippet that I am using to get the JSON data --

```
$.getJSON("http://dbpedia.org/data/Mountain_View,_California.json",
     function(data){
     console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Can you try again and tell me if it works?

Comment: Even this works now. It was because dbpedia was in maintenance mode. And i think they forgot to add the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header.

Comment: DBpedia switched to a new website and forgot to enable this particular header. I added it back yesterday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with JSONP instead.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://dbpedia.org/data/Mountain_View,_California.json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response ); 
    }
});
```

You can read more about jsonp and jquery here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#data-types